# Export phone numbers only?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, contacts

I'm curious if anybody knows a way to export only contacts that have a phone number added to them?

When I first bought my phone(Galaxy S3) I synced FB, Gmail, Hotmail, ... and now my contacts is full of email adresses etc.

Every app I see is has an export function that just exports everything.

I'd also like to sync stuff like FB/Gmail/Hotmail without the contacts being added, just to receive notifications.

If neccesary maybe I can just edit the CSV file(import to MySQL database and then just write a query to delete when there is no phone number or something)

Any thoughts? I've tried deleteing the synced accounts but the contacts don't go away